# Ionic2 - Not able to keep the radio alert as selected

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm implementing Radio Alerts in an Ionic2 app. I created a radio alert like this:

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
alert.setTitle('Select a Radio Alert');
alert.addInput({
  type: 'radio',
  label: 'Side A',
  value: 'a',
  checked: false
});
alert.addInput({
  type: 'radio',
  label: 'Side B',
  value: 'b',
  checked: false
});

alert.addButton('Cancel');
alert.addButton({
  text: 'OK',
  handler: data => {
    console.log('selected value '+data)
  }
});
alert.present();
```

It pops up when a user clicks on a button. I selected first radio button and clicked OK button and it looks like this.

[image]

When I open it again, the radio button I selected previously is not set as true. It does not remain as checked. Instead, it goes back to the initial state.

I'm trying to keep it as selected so that the user can see results accordingly to the value he/she selected.

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'radio-alert-demo',
  templateUrl: 'radio-alert-demo.html'
})
export class RadioAlertDemo {

  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  setFilter() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alert.setTitle('Select a Radio Alert');
    alert.addInput({
      type: 'radio',
      label: 'Side A',
      value: 'a',
      checked: false
    });
    alert.addInput({
      type: 'radio',
      label: 'Side B',
      value: 'b',
      checked: false
    });

    alert.addButton('Cancel');
    alert.addButton({
      text: 'OK',
      handler: data => {
        console.log('selected value '+data)
      }
    });
    alert.present();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the selected value in a property from your component, and use that property to check if any option should be selected *by default* when opening the alert:

```
public selectedFilter: any;

// ...

setFilter() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create(),
        firstInput = {
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Side A',
            value: 'a'
        },
        secondInput = {
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Side B',
            value: 'b'
        };

    // Set the status of each filter according to the selected value
    firstInput.checked = this.selectedFilter === 'a';
    secondInput.checked = this.selectedFilter === 'b';

    // Set the title
    alert.setTitle('Select a Radio Alert');

    // Add both inputs
    alert.addInput(firstInput);
    alert.addInput(secondInput);

    // Add the buttons
    alert.addButton('Cancel');
    alert.addButton({
        text: 'OK',
        handler: data => {
            console.log('selected value ' + data)

            // Save the selected value
            this.selectedFilter  = data;
        }
    });

    // Show the alert
    alert.present();
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)